# Everything except index.html gets 404 in Github Pages

Tags: github-pages

This is the Github page for my project.

https://bootsoon.github.io/ng-circle-progress/

Everything except index.html gives a 404 error and can't be loaded. I've tried locally and it works perfectly.

And it worked fine before I updated my gh-pages branch yesterday.

These files are indeed in repository: https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/blob/gh-pages/inline.073c4f038407ccd2fce1.bundle.js

But cannot be visited (404 error): https://bootsoon.github.io/inline.073c4f038407ccd2fce1.bundle.js

What am I suppose to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to https://bootsoon.github.io/ng-circle-progress/inline.073c4f038407ccd2fce1.bundle.js, where bootsoon is your username (or organization name), ng-circle-progress is your repo name, and inline.073c4f038407ccd2fce1.bundle.js is your file name. :)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. You saved my life. I've forgotten to add --base-href when building. The full command is `ng build --aot --prod --base-href ng-circle-progress`